# Chartjs not giving 'xLabel' properly on tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a line chart where data is displayed as point elements depending on the X axes (time axis) label.

[image]

```
    // Config chart
    const config = {
      type: "line",
      data: {
            labels: ['ene.', 'feb', 'mar.', 'abr.', 'may.', 'jun.', 'jul.', 'ago.', 'sep.', 'oct.', 'nov.', 'dic.'],
            datasets // ex --> [{ x: 'jun.', y: 90 }]
        },
      options: {
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    title: function(context) {
                             console.log(context); // Returning wrong xLabel 
                           }
                }
            }
      }
    }
```

The problem is when it shows the tooltip of, for example, June it takes it as index 3 so the title tooltip (xlabel) is shown as "April".

[image]

How could I get the proper label on the tooltip, not depending on the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For V2 this behaviour wont get fixed anymore. But you can get the correct labels by using the second argument in the callback which provides you with the data:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
        x: "Red",
        y: 5
      }, {
        x: "Blue",
        y: 5
      }, {
        x: "Purple",
        y: 5
      }, {
        x: "Orange",
        y: 5
      }],
      pointBackgroundColor: 'pink',
      borderColor: 'pink',
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'point',
      callbacks: {
        title: (ctx, data) => (data.datasets[ctx[0].datasetIndex].data[ctx[0].index].x)
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```